# How to add bcrypt to Spring security auth?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, bcrypt

I have spring security set up with JPA and JWT and it works fine for plain text passwords,

I tried to add Bcrypt but could not get it to workd

- I tried to get salt out of Stored password and encode the password in coming request, compare them to authenticate.

But I can't get the salt.

here's the code

```
//SecurityConfig
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

//Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/authenticate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
```

I save password like

```
//UserService
public User saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(userDto.getRoles());
        user.setActive(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to register BCrypt Password Encoders as Spring Bean also:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```